# Names of different cyclins

Tags: cell-biology, terminology, history, cell-division

Different types of cell cyclins are designated as a to y

Why are some letters like m, n, p, q.. etc. skipped?

[image: Cyclin families]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Biological nomenclature can be impenetrable. Almost certainly, at some point in history, there were cyclins designated with these letters. Researchers would have discovered apparently novel cyclins which were subsequently determined to be part of an existing family and renamed. For example, [this paper](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v409/n6822/full/409844a0.html) reports the discovery of:

> a new cyclin, cyclin M, which appears to be most closely related to cyclin L. Its biological function is unknown, but it is related to cyclins that regulate transcription.

It is now called [cyclin L2](http://www.genenames.org/cgi-bin/gene_symbol_report?hgnc_id=HGNC:20570).

I hope this answer satisfies you to some extent. I doubt anyone is going to sift through the literature and try and determine why all cyclins are are named as they are; that is certainly a losing proposition. The naming of genes/proteins is rather trivial and doesn't generally follow any specific set of rules. Outside of curiosity, the knowledge of cyclin naming doesn't have much, if any, practical relevance.

Answer (score 1):

Before directly answering your question, it's first worth mentioning that: within the table you provided, **each cyclin protein is actually being referenced to by using the name of the gene that codes for it**. That being said, in order to explain why the naming is the way it is, *we need to consider the naming system for genes!*

---

The institution that regulates gene naming is the [HUGO Gene Nomenclature Committee](http://www.genenames.org/), and within the HGNC website, they have a page that outlines the [gene naming guidelines](http://www.genenames.org/about/guidelines#genenames).

By considering the gene naming guideline page, and the [cyclin-coding gene family](http://www.genenames.org/cgi-bin/genefamilies/set/473), we can immediately say that the first three letters represent the CCN family, which stand for: **C**onnective tissue growth factor, **C**ystein rich protein, and **N**ephroblastoma overexpressed gene. ([source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1187011/#r1))

From there, the remaining *letters* in each acroynm represent the subfamily that the gene belongs to. These subfamilies are defined by a domain within the protein, and are abbreviated based on how that domain is named. For example, when considering CCNF, the *F* stands for "F-Box", which is a protein [structural motif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_motif) that, in this specific case, mediates protein-protein interactions.

---

**So, to now answer your question as to why the letters are skipped:** there is no specific reason (sorry to say it)! It really just comes down to who/when/how the protein motifs were discovered/named, and the fact that a single person/institution didn't discover them all, and that sometimes (quite often) biological naming isn't fixed after the fact to be so perfect.

A (somewhat) similiar situation of this can be seen with how vitamins are named.. they were originally named using the (English) alphabet, in a sequential manner upon discovery, but then it was decided to stop this convention (I'm not sure why), and upon doing so went go back and declassified some vitamins because they no longer conformed to newer standards, which broke the (nice) sequential naming that was originally in place. So, it truely is a purely historical reason, and has no meaning beyond that.

And lastly, just to be inclusive, the *number(s)* at the end of each acronym are used to uniquely identify the multiple members within each family.